# Generate unique random string and use each of them for different html tabs via php

Tags: php, html, tabs

I am working on html tabs via php, i want to generate ID for tabs via php (unique ID in href="#Uniqueid1")

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#uniqueid1" class="border-0 nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" >TAB1</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#uniqueid2" class="border-0 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" >TAB2</a></li>
```

and later use them via php for ID

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="uniqueid1">
    <ul class="icon-list">List 1</ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active" id="uniqueid2">
    <ul class="icon-list">List 2</ul>
</div>
```

any instruction will be great help!
Method to do it will be amazing!

Comment: unable to understand your problem please tell me where are you getting  issue

Comment: Why do you need these unique ids? Why not simple `id1`,`id2`,`id3` etc?

Comment: Seems to me a simple loop with a counter would do the trick

Comment: To avoid doing manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an array of ids using [for-loop](http://php.net/for):

```
<?php
$tabs=10;
$ids=[];
For($i=0;$i<$tabs;$i++){
$ids[]=$i;
}
?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<?php foreach($ids as $number):?>
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a href="#uniqueid<?=$number?>" class="border-0 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" >TAB<?=$number?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

And the blocks of data:

```
<?php foreach($ids as $number):?>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="uniqueid<?=$number?>">
                    <ul class="icon-list">List <?=$number?></ul></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: can you please tell me the way to store the data, i just need to store value of uniqueid in variable and then use that variable as id.
It will be short and effective!

Comment: @Nimesh just change the for loop to $ids[]=uniqid(); and make foreach loop to foreach ($ids as $key=>$number)

Answer (score 0):

PHP features a way to do this with `uniqid()`, also it allows to set a prefix.

Documentation [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

### Uniqueness

uniqid() does not ensure uniqueness because it relies on system clock (which can sometimes be outdated, then updated). Set the 2nd argument `$more_entropy` to true to strengthen uniqueness.

Example `$myId = uniqid('tabid-', true)`

Comment: if i want to get two different values  stored in two different variables and then use it as ID, how would i do it?